# How do I hide a table that has no data on ireport?

Tags: ireport

How do I hide a table (not include in layout) that has no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the table on its own band, what I typically do is set a print when condition on the band that only shows the data if any object in that band has data. Say your table is something like this:

```
item1 item2 item3
```

The print when expression would look something like this:

```
item1 != null || item2 != null || item3 != null
```

If you're referring to a subreport built using a collection, then I just check to make sure the collection isn't empty:

```
!subreportCollection.isEmpty()
```

Putting the print when condition on the band line hides the data, and causes the report to collapse the unused space.

Comment: OK, thank you for the help. my problem has already been solved.